# decode htmlentities of a file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, html-entities

How can I convert/decode html entities of a file's contents (XML) in PHP.

I tried to run this on a command line:

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -ne 'print decode_entities($_)' /apps/www/mydir/xmlfiles/p34580600.xml >> /apps/www/mydir/xmlfiles/p34580600_1.xml
```

It works fine running it on command line but when I try to call it within PHP:

```
system("perl -MHTML::Entities -ne 'print decode_entities($_)' /apps/www/mydir/xmlfiles/p34580600.xml >> /apps/www/mydir/xmlfiles/p34580600_6.xml");
```

It creates the file but it is empty.  I tried to use html_entity_decode but the XML file is just too big. 20megs at least.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try escaping the `$` in the system call. It is possible php is looking for a variable `$_` since you are using double quotes for the string command.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  thanks a lot Jonathan

Comment: posted as an answer so if it helped/worked you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try escaping the $ in the system call. It is possible php is looking for a variable $_ since you are using double quotes for the string command.